# how can I set different positions for jquery colorbox modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By default the colorbox appears centered both vertically and horizontally on the screen. Is there a way to change that, for example I have something like this:

1)foo   2)bar   2)bar   3)more   4)foobar   5)barfoo

now when the user clicks foo, I want colorbox to be displayed with left:20%, top:-200px; when user clicks on bar, I want colorbox to be displayed with the same top position(-200px) but this time, 50% to the left, click on more will be 60% to the left, foobar will be 70% to the left and so on. how can I possibly achieve this without having to set a class for each element and doing the css for all that? thanks

Comment: no I'm still working on it. Hopefully, I'll arise at a solution. :( You got the same problem?

Comment: my solution below didn't work for you - I was able to position each one relative to the previous one

Answer (score 0):

use the positioning settings

```
$('a#foo').colorbox({top:'-200px', left:'20%'});
$('a#bar').colorbox({top:'300px', left:'40%'});
```

I'm guessing something like this; I haven't tested but hopefully it will get you in right direction

```
 var topposition = '220';
 var leftposition = '10';
 $('a#bar').colorbox({top: topposition+'px', left:leftposition+'px', onComplete: function () {
    topposition = ($('#colorbox').offset().top) + 50;
    leftposition = ($('#colorbox').offset().left) + 10;
}});
```

take a look at this fiddle so you can see it in action
http://jsfiddle.net/4tkf5/13/

Comment: and that's what I want to avoid. setting the position for each of them. Can't I just make position like relative to the list. For example 2px to the left of each of them without having to hand code for each?

Comment: the fiddle add about 40px each time to the position for the onComplete function you could add some if statement if needed to determine the position and just update those variables each time

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do something like a dropdow menu.
You can use CSS to position everything where you want it as long as the color box item sits within the menu item.

The menu item would need to be position relative and the color box position absolute, then you can move them around using just the one class and hide and show them with the same class also.

Hope that helps